# Decrease time in objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a number of hours and a number of minutes, and I want a reduce the time of 1 second. So, I think I must create a nsdate object with my time, and after find the method to decrease the time. I looked in the apple documentation but I don't find how to do this.

Comment: What are you planning to do with the result? Why do you need an instance of `NSDate`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
NewDateString = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You want [NSDateComponents](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Note, you need to use it with a specific calendar. A code example is listed on the page to which I linked.

Answer (score 0):

Don't reinvent the wheel. There are many open source NSDate additions that you can use here. See [here](http://arstechnica.com/apple/guides/2010/03/how-to-real-world-dates-with-the-iphone-sdk.ars)